# .NET Core memory not released

Tags: memory-leaks, .net-core, windbg

Recently we had memory spike issue in one of our .Net core 2.0 application. When we analyze the memory dump, we found around 2GB of free space which is not released.

Following is the statistics from windbg tool.

```
Statistics:  
MT                  Count   TotalSize       Class Name  
000000e32eaf4ca0    15404   2584481422      Free
```

Can you please let me know what could be the reason for memory not getting released?

Comment: Too many pinned objects, typically.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the following reasons:

- .NET thinks that your program needs that memory again soon
- The free parts of the memory do not make up a complete block to give back to the OS

Regarding 1.), .NET might keep the memory which it got from the operating system, because giving it back to the OS and then reclaiming it from the OS has an impact on performance. If .NET thinks your program will request memory in the near future, it could simply "cache" it for you.

Regarding 2.), that's best explained in an example. Assume that your application requested 10 MB. .NET might take a 50 MB block from the OS. The application then requests 1 MB. .NET puts it into the existing 50 MB block. The 10 MB get freed. However, .NET cannot give 49 MB back to the OS, because giving memory back to the OS can only be done at the same size in which it was given.

.NET operates directly on [`VirtualAlloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`VirtualFree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366892(v=vs.85).aspx), therefore the possibilities are somewhat limited.

If you look at the `Count` column, you'll see that your 2.5 GB are not contiguous. It is split into 15000 fragments. Your program might suffer from memory fragmentation. Memory fragmentation can occur on the small object heap due to pinned handles and on the large object heap because that one does not get compacted.